# UWP XAML: Custom Brush to draw a progress bar as Grid background

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, brush

I have a Universal Windows App with a UI like this:

- A vertical grid defining an number of rows
- Each row is a horizontal grid with a number of columns

I'd like each row to have a progress bar in its background as shown in this mockup:

[image: Mockup]

I tried using a `ProgressBar` control with the `Grid.ColSpan` property set, but the progress bar is drawn *above* the text and buttons so that won't work.

My next idea was to use a Rectangle with a percentage width, but I don't think it's possible to specify a relative width.

My current idea is to implement a custom `Brush` that I can then set as `Background` property for each horizontal Grid, but I could not figure out how to do custom drawing inside my Brush implementation.

Sample XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <MyCustomBrush RelativeWidth="75%"/> ???
    </Grid.Background>

    <Button Content="{x:Bind ToggleSymbol, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0"></Button>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Title"></Button>

    <TextBlock Text="SubTitle" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>

    <ProgressBar Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Value="75" Maximum="100" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Red"></ProgressBar>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think the idea of using a rectangle was the best. Can you elaborate on why you didn't dot that?

Comment: @Muzib I didn't use a Rectangle control, because I don't know how to specify a relative width instead of points/pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions here: reorder your XAML and put your ProgressBar directly after your background definition and before your buttons. This will cause it to be drawn under the buttons (As XAML draws in the order it finds things in XAML files by default, so reordering the XAML results in things being drawn in different orders)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <MyCustomBrush RelativeWidth="75%"/> ???
    </Grid.Background>

    <ProgressBar Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Value="75" Maximum="100" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Red" />

    <Button Content="{x:Bind ToggleSymbol, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0"></Button>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Title"></Button>

    <TextBlock Text="SubTitle" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Another solution is to set the Canvas.ZIndex attached property on the ProgressBar to -1.

```xaml
<ProgressBar Canvas.ZIndex="-1" .... ></ProgressBar>
```

which will cause it to be drawn under the rest of the Grid's content, which be default will have a ZIndex of 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately both ideas did not work (ZIndex and XAML order). The progress bar is still drawn on top of the other elements.

Comment: Can you paste the XAML you've ended up for the first one? That should be functionally impossible unless you're doing something incorrectly. I've put what it should look like above, that I've confirmed works.

Comment: I used the XAML as above (without the Visibility=Collapsed). Only difference is that the Grid is embedded in a GridView and the Grid is actually part of the HeaderTemplate for the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you done , but what is the problem in getting this type of Design

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ProgressBar BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Foreground="LightCoral" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Value="7" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="▶ Title" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="50"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="▶ SubTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>

    <ProgressBar BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Foreground="LightCoral" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Value="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="▶ Title" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="50"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="▶ SubTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>

    <ProgressBar BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Foreground="LightCoral" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Value="8" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="▶ Title" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="50"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="▶ SubTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>

</Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can create your own glass effect for background progress bar , or use fluent design system